# Sending json file through Http Post curl

Tags: php, json, curl, jenkins, http-post

I have been working with Jenkins, and now Im stuck when I try to make an HTTP Post using curl, I am sending a json file, to a file in my page who is waiting for it, and then do some functions, the code I am using is the following:

curl -X POST -k -i -H "Accept: application/json" -w "%{body}" -w "%{http_code}" -d "@/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myFolder/session.json" http://mypage.com/myFolder/newfile.php

But apparently Im not sending correctly the data of the file, the newfile.php has something like this:

echo $_REQUEST['sessionId'];

But always get an error when I try to echo the index sessionId, I mean my file "newfile.php" is not getting anything from my jenkins curl, can you help me out?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON that you send is in the request body.  The keys/values will not be available in the `$_REQUEST` array, hence why you are getting the error.  You will need to access the request body in order to get the sessionId property.

```
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$session = json_decode($requestBody);
$sesionId = $session["sessionId"];
echo "Session ID: $sessionId";
```

The `file_get_contents('php://input')` returns the body of the POST request.

Make sure to also add the appropriate `Content-Type` header to your post request:

```
curl -X POST -k -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -w "%{body}" -w "%{http_code}" -d "@/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myFolder/session.json" http://mypage.com/myFolder/newfile.php`
```